# Signed 32-bit addition in batch file, giving Invalid Number

Tags: batch-file, 32-bit, signed

In the following script as part of the output, I get:
=-2147483648+312704
Invalid Number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.

This is obviously within the bounds of a signed 32-bit number
(I also tried 2147483648+312704 thinking that only unsigned 32 is supported), but got the same error.

Oddly enough, this script works fine on WindowsXP, but when I try it on Windows7, I get the above error.

Why won't batch perform this operation?

For convenience the code is below...

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@set TEMPDIR="%CD%\temp739123834543"
@set ADDR=-2147483648
@set HEXADDR=
@set /a ZIPSLEEP_MS=0

@del frontScreenImages.c
@del frontScreen.zip
@mkdir %TEMPDIR%

for %%f in (*.png) do (

    echo %%~nf
    @call toHex ADDR HEXADDR
    echo "ADDR:!HEXADDR!"
    convertFrontScreenPng.exe %%~nf.png frontScreenImages.c transpose append "0x!HEXADDR!" "__xdata_rom" "#pragma required="
rem    set BINFILE=%TEMPDIR%\a!HEXADDR!_%%~nf.bin
    set BINFILE=%TEMPDIR%\a80000000_frontScreenImages.bin
    echo "BIN:!BINFILE!"
    convertFrontScreenPng.exe %%~nf.png !BINFILE! transpose append
    for %%A in (!BINFILE!) do set /a ADDR=%ADDR%+%%~zA
    set /a ZIPSLEEP_MS=!ZIPSLEEP_MS! + 500
)

@echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
@echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
@echo wScript.Sleep !ZIPSLEEP_MS! >> _zipIt.vbs

@CScript  _zipIt.vbs  %TEMPDIR%  "%CD%\frontScreen.zip"

@del   _zipIt.vbs
@rmdir %TEMPDIR% /s /q
sleep 3
```

Comment: Try `set /a ADDR+=%%~zA` this prevents the MIN_INT value from being in-validated by the command line parser.  For some odd reason Windows 7 `set /a` supports holding values from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` but only allows values from `-2147483647` to `2147483647` in the equation.

Comment: [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758).

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it for me. I will mark as answered.

Comment: Also appreciate the link for how numbers are parsed. I had searched for such, but apparently in the wrong places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I repeat the answers of [David Ruhmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891976/david-ruhmann) and [Endoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098699/endoro) with some extra information.

It is explained at [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758) why value `-2147483648` results in an invalid number error message on parsing the number on Windows Vista, Windows 7 and perhaps also Windows 8 while there is no problem on Windows XP. The code for string to signed/unsigned int conversion is written poorly in source code of `cmd.exe` and therefore not working right for minimum signed 32-bit integer number.

One solution for this batch file is using

```
set /a ADDR+=%%~zA
```

instead of

```
set /a ADDR=%ADDR%+%%~zA
```

as this results in the command line

```
set /a ADDR+=312704
```

instead of

```
set /a ADDR=-2147483648+312704
```

But that is not the only solution for

```
@echo off
set VALUE1=-2147483648
set VALUE2=312704
set /a RESULT=%VALUE1%+%VALUE2%
echo Result of %VALUE1% + %VALUE2% is %RESULT%
```

resulting in an error message on execution on Windows 7 and Vista.

Another solution is what most `limits.h` for C/C++ contain for **INT_MIN** preprocessor macro to avoid same problem on poorly coded preprocessors: the definition of minimum signed 32-bit integer number as expression instead of fixed value.

```
#define INT_MIN  (-2147483647-1)
#define LONG_MIN (-2147483647L-1L)
```

This workaround solution applied to the small batch file from above:

```
@echo off
set VALUE1=(-2147483647-1)
set VALUE2=312704
set /a RESULT=%VALUE1%+%VALUE2%
echo Result of %VALUE1% + %VALUE2% is %RESULT%
```

Now there is no problem on execution of the batch file even on Windows 7 and Vista.